# How to create a meta description with categories?

Tags: html, plugins, search-engine, meta

I want my page meta description that is shown in the Google search to have options or categories like the ones in the photograph.
Does anyone know how to do it?

This is the result I am looking for.:
[image: This is the result I am looking for.]

Answer (score 0):

These are called "Sitelinks" and I believe Google automatically does this for you once Google has crawled your website. You can configure your search appearance by getting your website setup with [Google Webmasters Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/).

See more information about [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)